# Running junit tests using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, junit

I have some test cases to test an android application that I have written. I know that in Eclipse, I can just import the project, right click on it, and select Run as Android JUnit Test. Now I am working in Android Studio, and I can't find an option to do that. What would I need to do or change in order to run this? The test project can be found in the ActivityLabTest directory [here](https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android-labs/tree/master/TheActivityClass).

Comment: Check these official repos by google team: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint

and https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing ActivityLab, click on the "Project" tab on the left hand side. If "Android" is selected in the dropdown, it will look something like this:

[image: project menu]

There are two folders: ActivityLab and ActivityLabTest. Open up ActivityLab\java.

1. If you want to run all tests at the same time, right click on the folder with (androidTest) at the end (course.labs.activitylab.tests) and select "Run Tests in 'course.labs...'".
2. If you want to run the tests individually, open the folder course.labs.activitylab.tests, right click on the test you want to run, and select "Run".

**Note:** You do not need to import the test project. Android Studio will automatically import it into the application, as the second folder in app/java.